How to provide a status to questa vsim on detected test harness issue?
I had existing test benches with icarus verilog.  I am exploring questa.  The test benches can be called individually or batched.  With icarus it provides an extension to have a non-zero return code.  In an include, I use verilog macros to handle differences:
// Allow modsim/questa and other simulators to run.
// $finish_and_return iverilog extention allows *FAIL* status to halt
// make.  This will pause unit tests.  Otherwise, the output must be
// buffered (and non-real time).
`ifdef __ICARUS__
 `define RETURN_STAT(status) $finish_and_return(status)
`else
 `define RETURN_STAT(status) $finish()
`endif

`ifdef QUESTA
 `define TRACE(name) `"name.vcd`"
`else
 `define TRACE(name) `"name.lxt`"
`endif

Most of the unit tests behave identically, but I noticed one is different with questa (not part of this question, just the rationale).  So, I would like to modify  `RETURN_STAT to give a status code.  It is called from a TCL script.
# Simulate the design.
vsim -coverage -voptargs="+cover=bcesfx" $test_name -do "coverage save -onexit coverage.cov; run -all"

And then the calling vsim.exe -c -do questa.tcl returns to make.
This is a very similar question for VHDL, with no accepted answer, and I am not sure any of them translate to Verilog.  This portion Otherwise, the output must be
buffered (and non-real time). refers to a $display() that either prints 'PASS' or 'FAIL' and I could grep for this from the Makefile, but I need to capture all the output.  There is also a reg in the test bench called run_failed, if vsim can provide this value to TCL or an environment variable, I could use those.

I struggled with the 2000+ page Questa manual and overloaded 'examine' command for multiple languages (Verilog-SV/X, VHDL, TCL, etc.), different TCL environments, logging that is not consistent (goes to random places for console/batch builds).
Ultimately, I settled on $fopen() and $fclose().  I touch a file RUN_FAILED and use this existence in the Makefile to signal a status.  I converted all simulations to use this mechanism.  The fail cases are intended to be rare and this allows tests to terminate reliably with all simulators I am using.
There are probably a multitude of ways to do this with Questa, if you are willing to invest the time.  This is a simple solution that is easy to use in test harnesses and does not need to struggle with propagating values to different environments.
`define RETURN_STAT(status) \
  failed_fd = $fopen("RUN_FAILED", "w+"); \
  $fwrite(failed_fd, "%d", status);       \
  $fclose(failed_fd);                     \
  $finish()

And then in the Makefile,
rule: 
   rm -f RUN_FAILED
   # ...
   if [ -e RUN_FAILED ]; then false; fi  #Fail


Many obvious improvements to the main mechanics of using a file in the above psuedo-code.  Ie, this is not intended as some production example, just an overview of how easy it is to do with files.  I also considered pipes, but files are also cross platform.

Also a difference was an 'X' test clock signal transitioning to '1' during reset. Icarus had no clock, but Questa simulated one. It was an error in the test harness, so initially setting the clock to zero solved the issue, so both simulators had no initial clock edge during reset.
